# Bathroom exhaust fan with humidity sensor on one switch

Tags: bathroom, exhaust-fan

I have a recently remodelled old (OLD-1870) bathroom in a rental that needs an exhaust fan. (Why the exhaust fan wasn't done during the remodel? IDK).  I am looking at the WhisperValue DC Pick-A-Flow 50, 80, or 100 CFM [Installation manual](https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/fc/fc9b17bf-50eb-4a21-b4f9-cece9e41eee8.pdf).

The current wiring setup is one single gang switch for light fixture, and one GFCI outlet on opposite wall.  I would like to replace the standard GFCI outlet with an outlet switch combo to power the fan and leave one outlet for use. Like this

[image: Like this]

I would like to only have the switch control the power to the fan and have the humidity sensor control the fan operation while the power switch is on. I don't want to install another box or conduit to accommodate both fan power and operation switches, and I want the fan to run anytime the humidity goes up as long as the power switch is on (I don't want a separate fan control switch.)

[image: Panasonic fan wiring diagram]

The fan will be over a shower. And the diagram for the switch I see the power is on the line, I meant to show the fan on the load.

Thus my questions are below:

1. Can I just jump the two red 'control' wires for the fan together to make this happen? If not why and what else can I do?
2. Will this ensure the fan is GFCI protected?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Will this ensure the fan is GFCI protected

As currently shown in the image (text has a correction), the hot and neutral going to the fan are on the *LINE* side of the GFCI. In order for the fan to be GFCI protected, it needs to be on the *LOAD* side of the GFCI. Whether you can and/or how you can do that will depend on the particular GFCI/receptacle/switch that you use.

Comment: "_The fan will be over a shower._" - OP

Answer (score 0):

### Just nut off the two red wires separately

The "control" switch on your fan is essentially an override switch for the humidistat function, so if you nut the two red "control" wires off separately, then the fan will simply run as a humidistatic fan.